# How to print wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, masonry

As we know, to display posts on wordpress we must use a loop. But in general, the loop used to display posts on wordpress is as follows

```html
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$query = $query->get_posts();
 
foreach ($query as $post) :
the_post();
endforeach;
```

the question is, how do I get $post[$i] so that the results I will get are as follows.

```html
<!-- i want to print wordpress post like this format-->

<div class='grid'>

  <div class='column'>
  <!-- $i = 0 -->
  <!-- start loop -->
  <!-- print post -->
  <span><?php echo $post[$i]->title; ?></span>
  <!-- $i = $i + 3 -->
  <!-- end loop -->
  </div>

</div>
```

the concept is I want to display the first post based on the value of $i, then the next post based on the value of $i = $i + 3, so the final result will print $post[0], $post[3], $post[6], [...] , any suggestions?

sorry for my english, Thanks - Edwin.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: @JeroenHeier ok i edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the solution to display your posts:

```
<?php

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $posts->have_posts() ) : //checks if query have posts
        while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
            if( $i % 3 == 0 ) : //every third post ?>
                <div class='grid'>
                    <div class='column-<?php the_ID(); ?>'>
                        <span>the_title();</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;
            $i++;
        endwhile;
    else :
        // if no posts
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: how to print $post[0], $post[3], $post[6], [...] ?

Comment: @EdwinSulaiman, i updated my answer that you output every third id

Comment: Thanks, i will try this with some change

Answer (score 0):

i got this answer from other question and other forum

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    // Do your stuff, e.g.
    // echo $post->post_name;
}
```

and i make some change from the code to get my result

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$posts = $query->posts;

$i = 0;
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // Do your stuff, e.g.
    // echo $post[$i]->post_name;
$i = $i + 3;
}
```